# "Don't know how to convert parameter" error in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

When I run the below code, I am getting "Don't know how to convert parameter"error. I am trying islice to cut my name. Kindly help.

```
import ctypes
from itertools import islice

i = "sakthi srinivasan"
sliced_text =  islice(i, 0, 6)
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, sliced_text, "MsgBox", 0)
```

Comment: The message box expects you to give it a string, not a Python iterator object. Just pass it `i[0:6]`.

Comment: it works! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `MessageBoxW` is a string<sup>1</sup>. The function `itertools.islice` returns an iterator over the characters in `i`. Since ctypes can't figure out how to cast that to a character array, it throws the error "Don't know how to convert parameter...".

You could convert the iterator to a string with `''.join(sliced_text)`, but the best way to do so here is by using the slicing built into Python strings by passing `i[0:6]` as the second argument. That is the standard way to get a substring in Python.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Technically, an LPCTSTR, which is either a `const char*` or `const wchar_t*`, depending on whether or not you compile in UNICODE configuration.</sub>

Comment: Simon Hibbs answered the question for the OP in the comments, but I thought I'd provide a slightly more detailed answer for future readers. It will also keep this from looking like an unanswered question.